# Orchard CMS - Preferred method for feature switching when not using IDependency

Tags: c#, .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I want to feature switch a service implementation. This is easy to do by making Interfaces inherit IDependency and simply marking implementation with:

```
[OrchardFeature("MyFeature")]
[OrchardSuppressDependency("MyService1")]
```

There are a couple of reasons I can't use IDependency for this:

- I need to inject a named service into my implementations
- Interceptors need to be used with the services

Therefore, the implementations need to have an explicit autofac registration. To feature switch, I need to create 2 autofac registration modules and feature switch them.

My question is: Is this the preferred method? Is there another way that you can suggest to feature switch these autofac registrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom Autofac module is indeed the preferred way in case you need to do more complex registrations (like named or intercepted ones etc.). We use those a lot in Orchard core.

Autofac module in Orchard can be the subject to `OrchardFeature` as well as `OrchardSuppressDependency` attributes, making it a pretty powerful and easy to use solution when customization is required.